# Google Apps Script - copying TextStyles fails with Exception

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet

I am writing GAS script that copys some sheets from one spreadsheet to another - can't use copyTo as I don't want all the named ranges pulled in, for one thing.

A script gets data from one sheet, creating a sheet object, including the initializer:

textStyles: sheet.getLastColumn() != 0 ? sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getTextStyles() : [[]],

another  script copies the sheet info into a new sheet ...

newSheet.sheet.getRange(newSheet.sheetRange).setTextStyles(newSheet.textStyles);

which results in the error

Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setTextStyles.

I copied oldsheet -> newsheet using  let newSheet = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldSheet));
but I have tried :

newSheet.sheet.getRange(newSheet.sheetRange).setTextStyles(oldSheet.textStyles);

with the same result.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A short code sample I wrote works; so I have understood the get/setTextStyle interfaces correctly.  There must be a bug in my code rather than in my approach. I need to look harder!

Comment: The problem lies in deep copy of the google textStyles, richText and numberFormats.arrays. My code works fine if I set the new google sheet with the values gotten from the oldSheet.  But it fails when I use either 
let newSheet = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldSheet)); or
  let newSheet = loDashGS.cloneDeep(oldSheet); 
  to deep copy the oldSheet object to the newSheet object.  I found there are documented restrictions on what stringify can copy, and so probably for loDashGS too.

Comment: It can copy the google values or formulas arrays, but not these more advanced structures.  My workaround will be to initialize the more advanced structures by reading the values from the old google sheet both into my oldSheet object, and into the new sheet object rather than copying from one to the other.